# Get user count for there selection in survey C#

Tags: c#, windows, class

I'm writing out a code for a class activity in C#. One of the requirements are having to get how many times a user has selected the option then print it out. I've managed to get them to enter a valid input for all the questions which is just by typing 1, 2, or 3.

Can I print the amount of times it was selected at the end of the code? And also, how can I make them select a choice if they want to repeat all the questions again.

I'm stuck and don't know how to write it out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Week_3__wed_
{
    class Activity4
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("4 question Survey!");

            //Questions below with survey question while-looping until user input is 1, 2 or 3

            Console.WriteLine("How are you feeling?");
            Console.WriteLine("(1) Okay (2) Good (3) Really Good");
            int survey1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (survey1 < 1 || survey1 > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
                survey1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("How would you describe your mood?");
            Console.WriteLine("(1) Fine (2) Happy (3) Excited");
            int survey2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (survey2 < 1 || survey2 > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
                survey2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Do you have plans for today?");
            Console.WriteLine("(1) Yes (2) No (3) Possibly");
            int survey3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (survey3 < 1 || survey3 > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
                survey3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Have you had a good day so far?");
            Console.WriteLine("(1) Yes (2) Not Really (3) No!");
            int survey4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (survey4 < 1 || survey4 > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
                survey4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how much of this code have you written?  this remark "how can I make them select a choice if they want to repeat all the questions again." doesn't make sense, since you already have a while-loop, `Console.Readline` pattern that demonstrates 'how'.

Comment: "Can I print the amount of times it was selected at the end of the code".  The answer is yes; However, it's ***unclear*** whether you mean option per question or not. (i.e. 'how many times 1 was selected in all survey questions', or 'how many times 1 was selected for survey question 1'.. user repeated survey n times)

Comment: I've written the whole code. Since I have the user inputting 1, 2, or 3 for their answer to the questions. I want to be able to hold a count for the times they've selected that answer then display how much it has been selected. And at the end, I want to be able to ask them if they would like to repeat the same set of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code so that it does what you wanted:

```
int cont = 1;
while (cont == 1) // jut add while loop :)
{
    Console.WriteLine("4 question Survey!");

    int[] questionCount = new int[3]; // 3 options as answers
    //Questions below with survey question while-looping until user input is 1, 2 or 3

    Console.WriteLine("How are you feeling?");
    Console.WriteLine("(1) Okay (2) Good (3) Really Good");
    int survey1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (survey1 < 1 || survey1 > 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
        survey1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    questionCount[survey1 - 1]++; // increase count based on the answer

    Console.WriteLine("How would you describe your mood?");
    Console.WriteLine("(1) Fine (2) Happy (3) Excited");
    int survey2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (survey2 < 1 || survey2 > 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
        survey2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    questionCount[survey2 - 1]++;

    Console.WriteLine("Do you have plans for today?");
    Console.WriteLine("(1) Yes (2) No (3) Possibly");
    int survey3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (survey3 < 1 || survey3 > 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
        survey3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    questionCount[survey3 - 1]++;

    Console.WriteLine("Have you had a good day so far?");
    Console.WriteLine("(1) Yes (2) Not Really (3) No!");
    int survey4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (survey4 < 1 || survey4 > 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
        survey4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    questionCount[survey4 - 1]++;

    Console.WriteLine($"aswered 1 count: {questionCount[0]}"); // printing out the results
    Console.WriteLine($"aswered 2 count: {questionCount[1]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"aswered 3 count: {questionCount[2]}");

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to take the survey again?"); // asking whether they want to take the survey again
    Console.WriteLine("(1) Yes (2) No!");
    cont = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (cont < 1 || cont > 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice");
        cont = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

But if you have a lot of repeating code. If you are going to have more questions I would strongly suggest creating a class for it and use loops:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Question[] questions = new Question[]
        {
            new Question("How are you feeling?", "(1) Okay (2) Good (3) Really Good"),
            new Question("How would you describe your mood?", "(1) Fine (2) Happy (3) Excited"),
            new Question("Do you have plans for today?", "(1) Yes (2) No (3) Possibly"),
            new Question("Have you had a good day so far?", "(1) Yes (2) Not Really (3) No!")
        };
        bool cont = true;
        while (cont)
        {
            int[] ansCount = new int[3];
            foreach (Question q in questions)
                ansCount[q.Ask() - 1]++;
            for (int i = 0; i < ansCount.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine($"Answered {i + 1} count: {ansCount[i]}");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to repeat survey, or anything else to continue");
            cont = Console.ReadLine() == "1";
        }
    }
}

class Question
{
    public string Quest { get; private set; }
    public string Answers { get; private set; }
    public int Answer { get; private set; }
        
    public Question(string question, string answers)
    {
        Quest = question;
        Answers = answers;
    }

    public int Ask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Quest);
        Console.WriteLine(Answers);
        Answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((Answer > 3) || (Answer < 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid choise");
            Answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        return Answer;
    }
}
```